# SIGABRT when executing cobalt browser

Tags: cobalt

I would like to evaluate the performance & functionality of cobalt browser on my Ubuntu PC.
Then I follow the steps based on [this](http://youtube.github.io/cobalt/development/setup-linux.html) URL to build it.

However, I get the SIGABRT when launching it. 

Error message was

```
@ubuntu:~/cobalt/src/out/linux-x64x11_gold$ ./cobalt
```

> Caught signal: SIGABRT (6)
>      [0x7f077696ecc9]
>      [0x7f07769720d8]
>    [0x46e426]
>     cobalt::renderer::backend::TextureDataPBO::InitAndMapPBO()
>   [0x8b2920]
>     cobalt::renderer::backend::(anonymous
>   namespace)::RunAndSignal() [0x8b279d]
>      MessageLoop::RunTask()
>   [0x43536e]
>     MessageLoop::DoWork() [0x435a8a]
>     base::MessagePumpDefault::Run() [0x437c8a]
>   base::RunLoop::Run()
>   [0x43ef01]
>     MessageLoop::Run() [0x434d5a]
>     base::Thread::ThreadMain() [0x44f635]
>    base::(anonymous
>   namespace)::ThreadFunc() [0x45d231]
>    (anonymous
>   namespace)::ThreadFunc() [0x46e92b]
>    start_thread
>   [0x7f0777976182]
>    [0x7f0776a3247d]
>  Aborted (core
>   dumped)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might be running against a native GLES2 implementation which does not support PBOs, or at least does not support them the way Cobalt expects MesaGL to support them. Cobalt does not yet use proper GL feature testing.

See if you have other GL libraries installed and uninstall them and try again, or otherwise make sure you are building and running against MesaGL.

Comment: Yeah exactly.  By default Cobalt on the linux-x64x11 platforms will assume that GLES3 is available, and if so, it will use some GLES functions around PBOs that are only available in GLES3.  You could try using a different EGL driver that does have GLES3 support, or you can modify src/starboard/linux/shared/gyp_configuration.gypi and substitute "system_gles3" with "system_gles2".